# Openshift 3.10 how to create template from existing objects

Tags: openshift

The new `oc get --export` implementation is not same as the old oc export (from 3.10 onward). `--as-template` is one of the missing option in the new export command and I am not able to find any workaround so far.

`oc get -o yaml --export all` will return only objects as type list and not as type template.

How can I export the objects as template (and not as type list)?

Comment: The docs say that `--as-tremplate` is the solution for 3.x. But read the docs because they suggest using `all`, Make sure you tell us what steps you have taken to solve this so potential answers don't go over the same ground.

Comment: sure, but no luck so far. As of 3.10 `--as-template` is deprecated and soon will be removed (probably from 4.x). The new export option output the objects as list even for 'all'. Not really sure how to export as template.

Comment: Maybe this is one of those times to see if you can grab the beta/future docs and see what they say. And/or raise it with the vendor.